# Connection between the Traffic Manager and the Endpoint system in Mashery API Management solution

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, kerberos, ibm-api-management, mashery

I would like to know if it is possible for Mashery solution to expose backend services that are secured with OAuth 2.0 or Kerberos.
My idea is to hide this authentication by Mashery Traffic Manager, for the services that are secured with a basic authentication it works very well but for the rest I do not have connectors on my administration panel.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from regular open ones and endpoints with API key authentication where key is passed as a query parameter(or feasible urlpath), as of now Mashery can handle the backends with Client SSL Certificate and HTTP Basic Authentication only, which you can set in in 'Security Settings' of the endpoints.

No oAuth2.0 is possible and I don't think they have any plans to implement it in recent future.